# How to renumber column sequence values with subsequence column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, sequence

I have a table that contains columns StructureNumber and SubStructureNumber.  StructureNumbers are numbered sequentially starting with 1 for each PropertyId.

Child structures can exist for a structure, in which case SubStructureNumber will be > 0, with the same StructureNumber as the parent (top-level) structure.

Top-level structures have a SubStructureNumber of 0, while SubStructures (children of a top-level structure) are numbered sequentially starting with 1.

Example data:

```
PropertyId | StructureNumber | SubStructureNumber
144        | 1               | 0
144        | 2               | 0
197        | 1               | 0
197        | 2               | 0
197        | 3               | 0
197        | 3               | 1
197        | 3               | 2
```

The challenge comes when a structure is deleted for a Property.  For example, if StructureNumber 2 for PropertyId 197 is deleted, I need to renumber the structures for that Property to fill in the missing number.

```
PropertyId | StructureNumber | SubStructureNumber
197        | 1               | 0
197        | 3               | 0
197        | 3               | 1
197        | 3               | 2
```

Likewise, if a SubStructure is deleted, I need to renumber SubStructureNumbers for each StructureNumber:

```
PropertyId | StructureNumber | SubStructureNumber
197        | 1               | 0
197        | 3               | 0
197        | 3               | 2
```

I know how to accomplish renumbering the StructureNumbers using a CTE as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503151/how-to-renumber-rows-by-groups), using something like this:

```
DECLARE @PropertyId int = 197;
WITH Renumber AS
(
SELECT
    StructureNumber, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY os.StructureNumber DESC, 
        os.SubStructureNumber DESC) as StructureNumberNew
    FROM dbo.parcel_OtherStructures os
    WHERE os.PropertyId = @PropertyId
    ORDER BY os.StructureNumber DESC, os.SubStructureNumber DESC
)
UPDATE Renumber SET StructureNumber = StructureNumberNew;
```

I just don't know how to also renumber SubStructureNumbers for each StructureNumber without advancing the ROW_NUMBER() value for StructureNumber for those rows.

I saw mention of using DENSE_RANK also but don't know how to use it to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. I guess this is what you are looking for

```
select 
    *, dense_rank() over (partition by PropertyId order by StructureNumber) as StructureNumber
    , row_number() over (partition by PropertyId, StructureNumber order by SubStructureNumber) - 1 as SubStructureNumber
from 
    myTable
```